# How can I make something like the Stack Overflow tag popover?

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, tooltip, effect

In Stack Overflow's web sites if you put the mouse pointer over a tag name you will see the screenshot below.

What is the name of this effect (tooltip)? Is there a library (in jQuery, BTW) that would allow me to do the same effect?

[image: screenshot of the question]

Comment: @juque - off-topic - with what tool did you make the screen capture?

Comment: @Kees with http://skitch.com/ - if you use mac, is very useful.